# asp.net Web application Handle global variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, global-variables, static-variables

How can I define and initialize global variables in my asp.net web API project that is deployed in IIS
Here are my two cases

I need to have a global variable look like this which can be accessed all over the code, from web API to instances that I create inside the web API

my global variable will look like this

`DataTable property = GetPropertyValuesFromDb()`

this property will not change until I restart IIS or republish the project

I don't want to load the values from the database each time
It needs to be set at once and can be accessed by all subprojects

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose there is file named appsettings.json. You can define your variables
there and then access them though the Configuration variable like.

`Configuration.getSection('SectionName')`

or

`Configuration.getSection('SectionName:SubSectionName')`

Confiuration can be accessed in Startup class and also it can be injected to controllers or services that you are using in DI container. Just add parameter of IConfiguration type to constructor of controller or service from DI container.

But it is not recommended to use appsettings.json for storing secret variables like connection strings on production. This variables should be stored in production environment and they can also be accessed like it was mentioned above.

Comment: static constructor was the answer I was looking for, but this answer help me to solve another problem, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can let you API inherit from a base API where this variable is stored.

Example code

base API

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]    
public class BaseController : ControllerBase
{

   public static DataTable _property;         

          public BaseController()
          {
            _property = GetPropertyValuesFromDb()
          }
}
```

Main API that inherits from your base API

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]    
public class SomeController : BaseController 
{
 
   public SomeController():base()
   {

   }
    
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("SomePath")]
    public string SomeMethod()
   {
       /*Access datatable here*/
       _property
   }
}
```

Comment: I didnt get how this gonna helps from loading data from database for first time only

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new project in the solution that contains the static class. It exists as a constant. in the end you add the references to the main project

Comment: static class with static constructor will solve this, just a static class does not help me in loading data from the database, if I do this it will be called multiple times,